# QtService and QtRemoteObject how to make then work togather

Tags: qt, service

I am trying to develop a service which remote some custom QObject (Actually this QObject access some database and present some statistics). To this end I used QtService along with QtRemoteObject, when I host the remote object in a simple QCoreApplication everything is good, I can connect to the host and run the slots or get the signals, but when I host the remote object on the QtService based app, I can't connect to the host, At first I thought about the firewall, so I added an inbound-outbound rule for the application but still does not work.
The code is a little bit big (serval files) if you need any portion of it, I will provide it.

service class:

```
#include <QtService>
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QRemoteObjectHost>
#include "affairstatero.h"

class AffairStateService : public QtService<QCoreApplication>
{
public:
    explicit AffairStateService(int argc, char** argv, const QString& name = "affair_state");

    // QtServiceBase interface
protected:
    void start() override;
    void stop() override;
    void pause() override;
    void resume() override;

private:
    AffairStateRemoteObject* _affairStateRO;
    QRemoteObjectHost* _remotingHost;
};
```

cpp:

```
#include "affairstateservice.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include <QSqliteSettings>

AffairStateService::AffairStateService(int argc, char **argv, const QString &name):
    QtService(argc,argv,name)
{
    this->setServiceDescription("report affair states.");
    this->setServiceFlags(QtService::CanBeSuspended);
    qDebug() << "service starting ...";
}

void AffairStateService::start()
{
    _affairStateRO = new AffairStateRemoteObject();
    _remotingHost = new QRemoteObjectHost();
    qInfo() << "Starting the service";
    QSqliteSettings settings;
    qInfo() << "Settings filename " << settings.fileName() << settings.organizationName() << settings.applicationName();
    _affairStateRO->startTimer();
    _remotingHost->setHostUrl(QUrl(settings.value("endpoint").toString()));
    _remotingHost->enableRemoting(_affairStateRO, "AffairStateRO");
    qInfo() << "Remoting on " << _remotingHost->hostUrl().toString();
    qInfo() << "Done";
}

void AffairStateService::stop()
{
    _affairStateRO->stopTimer();
    _remotingHost->disableRemoting(_affairStateRO);
}

void AffairStateService::pause()
{
    _remotingHost->disableRemoting(_affairStateRO);
}

void AffairStateService::resume()
{
    _remotingHost->enableRemoting(_affairStateRO);
}
```

INFO: Windows 10/x64 - Qt 5.9.1 MCVS2017

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I will answer my own question, the problem was that on the server side I give a name to the remoted object by doing `QRemoteObjectHost::enableRemoting(&object,"Object");` but on the client side I was just acquiring a replica without giving the source name like `QRemoteObjectNode::acquire<ObjReplica>();`.

I don't know exactly but I guess QtRemoteObject set the object remoted without a name as default object which is acquired without a name, but when naming the remoted object we need to acquire the replica with the that same name, even if the source is remoting just one object.

When on the server side remoting the object as `QRemoteObjectHost::enableRemoting(&obj, "Object");`, on the client side we need to `QRemoteObjectNode::acquire<ObjReplica>("Object");`

It was nothing related to the QtService.